# How to select one value from row and update anotther row without a loop?

Tags: python, pandas

I have such dataframe:

```
+----------------------------+
| id_process proc_name score |
+----------------------------+
| 1          Mark        5   |
| 2          Mark        0   |
| 3          John        3   |
| 4          Ann         2   |
| 5          Ann         7   |
| 6          Ann         0   |
+----------------------------+
```

I want to select all proc_names, which have score 0, and set some another value (i.e 1) to column "score" to rows, which have the same proc_name.

So, in this example the resulting dataset must be as that (one score value changed at Mark, and two score values changed at Ann, John not changed):

```
+----------------------------+
| id_process proc_name score |
+----------------------------+
| 1          Mark        1   |
| 2          Mark        0   |
| 3          John        3   |
| 4          Ann         1   |
| 5          Ann         1   |
| 6          Ann         0   |
+----------------------------+
```

How can I do this without using loops?

Answer (score 0):

IICU

Introduce count

```
df['count']=df.groupby('proc_name')['proc_name'].transform('count')
```

Mask by condition

```
m=(df['score']>0)& (df['count']>1)
```

apply condition

```
df['score']=np.where(m,1,df['score'])
```

Drop count if not needed

```
df.drop(columns=['count'],inplace=True)
```

Outcome

[image]

Comment: interesting solution but if you try to add duplicate of the record `John` probably result won't be correct

Comment: Thats what I understood it to be. set to 1 if the names are duplicated and the score is not zero.

Comment: probably first condition is `select all proc_names, which have score 0`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using numpy's `where` function!

```
df['score']=np.where((df.score > 0) & (df.proc_name.isin(df[df.score==0].proc_name)),1,df['score'])
```

Replace `score` if score is greater than 0 and if `proc_name` exists in list of `proc_name`s that have score = 0.

Know more about `numpy.where` [here](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).